# It's it possible to bundle a jar inside a Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to write a Jenkins plugin that uses YUI compressor. Is it possible somehow to bundle the yui jar file with/inside my pluigin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to add the dependency into the pom.xml file (assuming you are using Maven) and when you build the hpi file it will include it

add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

into you dependencies - taken from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yahoo.platform.yui/yuicompressor/2.4.7